# use jabber to implement a chat room feature

Tags: chat, xmpp

I have a existing web app and a iphone app for a closed user community.  I want to add chat room feature for users to chat with each other.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel.   Is it a good choice to use jabber on the backend to handle chats/chatroom?  If yes, can you point me to some tutorials?

My users won't need to know anything about jabber.  My chat system won't  allow users from gtalk or other jabber-compatible to connect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Jabber is a good choice indeed. You could have a look at [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/), a popular jabber server.

For implementing your "private" jabber chat room, you can easily write "modules" for ejabberd that would enforce the "private chat rooms" e.g. enforcing access rights etc.